# How to animate/make a gasoline spill pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to create/animate patterns like this, rainbow colors arranged in a gasoline spill pattern:

[image]
[image]

I know you can do some chromatic abherration alterations using smudge tool in photoshop, but how would I do something like the first image? Or animate the effect? Any pointers?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Scott as I said I have tried smudge tool and separating RGB channels in Photoshop. Beyond that I dont know where to begin